# rock-zapping -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Example ([NASA's Curiosity Rover Eyes Weird Rock On Mars](http://www.space.com/30062-mars-rover-curiosity-weird-rock.html)):

> Measurements by Curiosity's **rock-zapping** ChemCam laser and another instrument revealed that the target, a chunk of bedrock dubbed Elk, contains high levels of silica and hydrogen, NASA officials said.

What exactly does that adjective mean?

Comment: The laser beam disintegrates the substance for analysis.  To "zap" is to direct a high-energy beam or pulse at something.

Comment: The "rock-zapping ChemCam laser" refers to the laser fired by Curiousity's rock-vaporizing laser gun. From [Zap! Laser Sparks Fly on Mars in Curiosity Rover Video](http://www.space.com/26550-mars-rover-curiosity-laser-flash-video.html): *NASA's Curiosity rover on Mars has set off some fireworks on the Red Planet with the zap-zap-zap of its high-tech space laser.*

Comment: Odd compound words are not definable in a dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why the comments above are not answers, because they are valid.

"Zap" is an onomatopoeia for the sound that high voltage electricity makes when it ionizes air. As such it's been used in science fiction since at least the 1940s to represent the sound of laser based weaponry. It is used here facetiously to introduce a little humor and light-heartedness into the potentially very dry subject of gas spectroscopy.

Comment: The "bug-zapper" comes to mind: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClwwP9cYK6A